# Redirect all non www HTTPS request to www HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to redirect all requests from https://example.com to https://www.example.com.

I can able to access the application without www and with www.

wwww.example.com is an ALIAS for an application Load Balancer also configured ACM certificate for an application.

Currently, DNS entities configured in Route53.

please find the Network Loadbalancer rule has defined below. But if someone has enter like that https://example.com it doesn't direct to https://www.example.com.

**Rules :**

```
Redirect tohttps://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}
Status code:HTTP_301
```

please suggest me how to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Application Load Balancer you should set up a listener rule on your https listener, i.e. the one listening on port 443, that has a redirect action to change the host from the root to the www subdomain.

#{host} is the original host, example.com, www.#{host} would therefore be www.example.com

Redirect to:

- Protocol: #{protocol}
- Port: #{port}
- Custom host: www.#{host}
- Original path: #{path}
- Original query: #{query}
- 301 - Permanently moved

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#redirect-actions

Comment: do we need to change anything in route53? Currently route 53 has A record for www.mypage.com. For http listeners i created a 2nd rule for host mypage.com to forward to 443 https www.mypage.com.  But when i type in http://mypage.com in url it doesnt send me to https://www.mypage.com

Comment: You need an A record for mypage.com as well as www.mypage.com. Otherwise mypage.com doesn’t resolve to your load balancer to hit your redirect

Comment: @NHol what if we need both www.example.com and example.com coming to port 80 of Application load Balancer  redirected to to https://www.example.com via the default rule.